# TypeORM: exclude seed from subscriber

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

Im currently working with TypeORM library, and Im having issue with seeds & subscribers
The problem is every time I run seed for users, my subscriber is triggered and record new inserts 
How can I exclude inserts that are comming from seed, and only record the ones that are preformed trough App UI

```
import { EntitySubscriberInterface, EventSubscriber, InsertEvent, UpdateEvent } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../users/user.entity';


@EventSubscriber()
export class HistorySubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<User> {
    /**
     * Indicates that this subscriber only listen to User events.
     */
    listenTo() {
        return User;
    }

    /**
     * Called before User insertion.
     */
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<User>) {
          // this gets called multiple times even with seed
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each database operation (query) it can be specified if listeners should be called: See [SaveOptions](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/repository/SaveOptions.ts#L16) and [QueryBuilder](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts#L463). So for your seeds, disable listeners/subscribers for each database operation.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me again :)

Comment: One more question how can I use listeners option in createQueryBuilder() ????

Comment: You can configure the behaviour through the fluent api: `await getCustomRepository(User).createQueryBuilder().insert().callListeners(false). //...`.

Comment: @Loki Glad I could help :)